# Form Input displayed above text field using flexbox

Tags: css, flexbox

I am trying to create a form using flexbox and what I'd like is for the label fields to be above the text input fields, and displayed in a row. Currently, my form is display in a row, but I cannot get the label fields to sit on top of the input. Any suggestions would be great.

```
       <form>
        <div class="form-container">
          <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="first-name">
          <label for="middle-name">Middle Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="middle-name">
          <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="last-name">
        </div>
      </form>

    .form-container {
      margin: 2rem 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this out.

```css
  .form-container {
      margin: 2rem 0;
      display: flex;
      justify-content: flex-start;
    }
.form-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction : column;
  margin-right: 40px;
}
```

```html
  <form>
        <div class="form-container">
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="first-name">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="first-name">  
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="middle-name">Middle Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="middle-name">  
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-group">
          <label for="last-name">Last Name</label>
          <input type="text" name="last-name">  
          </div>

        </div>
      </form>
```

Comment: If I try to add more fields, like radio buttons and then an email address, and want them to be placed directly underneath the name fields, would I need to create a new form-group?

Comment: For that you can create new form-groups and give your form-group a width of 25%. Then add `flex-wrap: wrap;` this will allow them to break and start a new row. i have created a pen, look https://codepen.io/bhanusinghR/pen/rNBZQRj

Comment: I see how that works, but if the screen size is large, it still shows  all the items in a row. What I'm trying to do is have the name fields in a row, then underneath that have the radio buttons, then underneath that have the email. I dont want them all to be in a row so it's really a column display, aside for the name text fields in a row. That may sound confusing.

Comment: This may be clearer, I'd like each section of form fields to be on its own row. So first name middle last  next row radio buttons next row email address

Comment: If I am understanding it correctly then you want different row section for different type of fields. In that case you should create multiple form-container and each container should have there kind of fileds. I have updated the codepen, check :  https://codepen.io/bhanusinghR/pen/rNBZQRj

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap each input in the label like so:

```css
.form-container {
  margin: 2rem 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.form-container input {
  display: block
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-container">
    <label>First Name <input type="text" name="first-name"/></label>
    <label>Middle Name <input type="text" name="middle-name" /></label>
    <label>Last Name <input type="text" name="last-name" /></label>
  </div>
</form>
```